# Adding several ArrayList elements into one ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I have several "ArrayList"

Like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list1;
ArrayList<Integer> list2;
ArrayList<Integer> list3;




  list1: [0,1,2]
  list2: [22,12,23,24,53]
  list3: [21,43,21,7]
```

I want to put all elements of all lists into one ArrayList like

```
sumList [0,1,2,22,12,23,24,53,21,43,21,7]
```

How is that to be done?

thx u

Comment: [Research effort helps sometimes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use addAll :

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(list1);
list.addAll(list2);
list.addAll(list3);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to have a single toolkit method:

```
public static <T> List<T> merge(List<T>...args) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>(args[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++)
        list.addAll(args[i]);
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1.addAll(list2);
list1.addAll(list2);
```